# is multiple <Picker> within a <view> is possible?

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

If I need to use `<Picker>..</Picker>` more than once within a `<View>..</View>` how can I pick the selected VALUE of different `<Picker>` as `this.state.PickerValue` gives the selected value.

Comment: Create a component that implement `Picker` with its own state.

Comment: Would you please explain it with some example ? @Striped

Comment: keep the state and the onValueChange listener seperate

Comment: Made a simple demo for you @FaisalAhmed check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

Constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       language: '',
       level: '',
    };
}
```

You render method

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Picker
       selectedValue={this.state.language}
       style={{ height: 50, width: '100%' }}
       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ language: itemValue })}>
       <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
       <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
    </Picker>

    <Picker
       selectedValue={this.state.level}
       style={{ height: 50, width: '100%' }}
       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ level: itemValue })}>
       <Picker.Item label="Beginner" value="beginner" />
       <Picker.Item label="Intermediate" value="intermediate" />
       <Picker.Item label="Professional" value="professional" />
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Check out the [live demo here](https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/multiple-picker-demo)

Read more about [Picker API here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use different state values, one for each picker.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Picker } from 'react-native';

class PickersComp extends Component {
  state = {
    val1 : '',
    val2: '',
    val3: '',
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.val1}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ val1: itemValue })}>
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
        </Picker>

        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.val2}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ val2: itemValue })}>
          <Picker.Item label="foo" value="foo" />
          <Picker.Item label="bar" value="bar" />
        </Picker>

        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.val3}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ val3: itemValue })}>
          <Picker.Item label="test" value="test" />
          <Picker.Item label="test2" value="js" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```